# Reduce bibliography to one line with dots and reference numbers

Tags: bibliographies, natbib, paragraphs

I would like my references to look like

> • [ 1 ] Foo et al. 2008, Nature, 100, 200 • [ 2 ] Bar & Baz et al. 2010, Science, 300, 400 • [ 3 ] Einstein, 1905, New Scientist, 5, 6

and so on.

To do that I am using the following code kindly suggested by Mico:

```
\usepackage[sort&compress,numbers]{natbib}
\let\olditem\item
\renewenvironment{thebibliography}[1]{%
\par\noindent
\raggedright
\textsc{\textbf{References}}
\let\par\relax\let\newblock\relax
\renewcommand{\item}[1][]{\textbullet~\olditem}
% \inparaitem[{[}1{]}]}{\endinparaitem}
\inparaenum}{\noindent\hspace*{\fill}\endinparaenum}
```

with a bibtex style unsrtnat.

However, this code adds annoying spaces between the dot and the numeric reference. Moreover this space varies arbitrarily as shown below:

[image]

Do you know any way to remove the spaces? Thanks very much!

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!

Comment: would it be okay to have an "annoying space" before rather than after the bullet? (i'm thinking of putting a fixed space between bullet and text, but letting the separation between entries be more flexible.)

Comment: Can you create a minimal woring example that recreates the behaviour?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because a minimal working example is still missing.