# Extra space between entries in references when putting them on one line using natbib's numbers option

Tags: spacing, bibtex, natbib

(Note: I wasn't sure if this fell under the same question as [reduce bibliography to one line with dots and reference numbers](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/313843/reduce-bibliography-to-one-line-with-dots-and-reference-numbers). I attempted an edit which was rejected due to changing the question too much, so I'm asking this as a new question instead.)

I'm trying to put my references on one line, using code from Mico:

```
\usepackage[numbers]{natbib}
\renewenvironment{thebibliography}[1]{%
    \section*{\refname}
    \let\par\relax\let\newblock\relax
    \inparaenum[{[}1{]}]}{\endinparaenum}
```

However, this produces extra spaces between some entries:

[image]

Note the extra space between the end of entry 2 and the beginning of entry 3.

Adding the following code fixes the extra space, but makes all in-text citations show up as question marks:

```
\renewcommand{\bibitem}[2][]{\item}
```

In addition, removing the `numbers` option from `\usepackage{natbib}` gets rid of the extra space as well, but I'd like to avoid using author-year citations.

Does anyone know how to get rid of the extra space while using the numbers option, without breaking in-text citations?

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[numbers]{natbib} % Removing numbers option fixes extra space
\usepackage{paralist}

\begin{filecontents}{bib.bib}
    @article{test1,
        Author = {Test Test},
        Year = {0000},
        Title = {Some title},
        Journal = {Some journal},
        Volume = {0},
        Pages = {0}
    }
    @article{test2,
        Author = {Test2 Test2},
        Year = {0001},
        Title = {Some other title},
        Journal = {Some other journal},
        Volume = {1},
        Pages = {1}
    }
    @article{test3,
        Author = {Test3 Test3},
        Year = {0002},
        Title = {Yet another title},
        Journal = {Yet another journal},
        Volume = {2},
        Pages = {2}
    }
\end{filecontents}

% Redefine the bibliography to go on one line
\renewenvironment{thebibliography}[1]{%
    \section*{\refname}%
    \let\par\relax\let\newblock\relax
    \inparaenum[{[}1{]}]}{\endinparaenum}

% Uncommenting the following makes the extra space go away but breaks in-text citations   
%\renewcommand{\bibitem}[2][]{\item}

\begin{document}
    \citet{test1,test2,test3}
    \bibliography{bib}{}
    \bibliographystyle{plainnat}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I've since figured out that this has to do with the `\hfil` in the `\item` command in `\@lbibitem`. Unfortunately, trying to redefine `\@lbibitem` in the document's preamble results in me getting an error about the paragraph ending before `\NAT@bare` is complete. I'm not sure if there are any terrible consequences to redefining `\hfil` to `\hskip 0pt plus 0fil minus 0pt`, or if there's a way to avoid the `\NAT@bare` error to allowing for removing it from `\@lbibitem` directly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As your comment says you want to remove the `\hfil` in the `\item` statement in the `\@lbibitem` macro.  Concretely it appears as

```
   \item[\hfil\NAT@anchor{#2}{\NAT@num}]%
```

in `natbib.sty`.  You can use `etoolbox` to do the replacement for you as follows:

```
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\@lbibitem}{\item[\hfil}{\item[}{}{}
\makeatother
```

once `natbib` is loaded.  Note the use of `\makeatletter...\maketother` around this code, because of the presence of the `@` in the macro name, cf. [\makeatletter explained](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/106174/15925)

[image: Sample output]

```
\begin{filecontents}{bib.bib}
    @article{test1,
        Author = {Test Test},
        Year = {0000},
        Title = {Some title},
        Journal = {Some journal},
        Volume = {0},
        Pages = {0}
    }
    @article{test2,
        Author = {Test2 Test2},
        Year = {0001},
        Title = {Some other title},
        Journal = {Some other journal},
        Volume = {1},
        Pages = {1}
    }
    @article{test3,
        Author = {Test3 Test3},
        Year = {0002},
        Title = {Yet another title},
        Journal = {Yet another journal},
        Volume = {2},
        Pages = {2}
    }
\end{filecontents}
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[numbers]{natbib}
\usepackage{paralist}
\usepackage{etoolbox}


% Redefine the bibliography to go on one line
\renewenvironment{thebibliography}[1]{%
    \section*{\refname}%
    \let\par\relax\let\newblock\relax
    \inparaenum[{[}1{]}]}{\endinparaenum}

\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\@lbibitem}{\item[\hfil}{\item[}{}{}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\citet{test1,test2,test3}

\bibliography{bib}
\bibliographystyle{plainnat}

\end{document}
```